# Ключевое слово void и возврат из функции

Tags: java

Хотел спросить, читаю в данный момент литературу по Java, но так и не понял почему void ничего не возвращает.

Например:

```
public void firstMethod(){
System.out.println("Hello!");
}
```

По сути, нам возвращается слово "Hello" как я понимаю.

Но забил в Intellij idea код:

```
public void run(){
   return 10;
 }
```

Идея начала ругаться, мол измените на `public int run()`.

Не очень понял (ничего не возвращающий void), объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция должна возвращать какою-то структуру при её вызове (или же ничего не возвращать). void - спецификатор, который указывает, что функция не должна ничего возвращать. Важно отметить, что под возвратом понимается return {...}, а не сама работа функции. Т.е. если у вас функции вида int Method(), то в самой функции обязательно должен присутствовать возврат return .

Void же такого возврата не предполагает. Однако return может служить для досрочного завершения работы функции.

Comment: Если подробнее о возврате. То в твоем случае вызов firstMethod() в основном методе ничего не возвратит. А вот если бы функция была int firstMethod() и в ней был возврат "return 0;", то вызов int a = firstMethod() занес бы в переменную a значение 0.

Answer (score 3):

Имеется ввиду, что не возвращается никаких значений переменных. Соответственно тип возвращаемого значения не указывается и пишется void.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы вызываете какой-либо метод в коде, представляйте себе в уме вместо него то, что хотите от него получить. Что происходит в теле метода в это время нас не интересует: там может что-то печататься на консоль, могут создаваться какие-то объекты, могут даже вызываться другие методы или все сразу. Главное - это то, что он должен вернуть на свое место, когда его вызывают.
Посмотрите на этот пример:

```
public static **int** sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int sumResult = sum(15, 23);
```

И на этот:

```
public static **void** sumAndPrint(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println(a + b);
}
```

Первый метод мы можем использовать, чтобы, вызывая его, сразу записать результат в какую-то переменную. Второй же метод ничего не возвращает и может использоваться... ну, просто так, чтобы посмотреть на результат в консоли.